# Regex characters should be replaced as a text in perl

Tags: perl, latex

I have two input files one is *TEX file and *INI.

INI file contains: (User can add if some more patters but this way)

```
\bra{([^{}]*)}  \langle $1|\sprangle
\ket{([^{}]*)}  \splangle|$1\rangle
\braket{([^{}]*)}   \langle $1\rangle
\set{([^{}]*)}  \{$1\}
```

INPUT file contains:

```
\bra{ahdhaodoaddo4092039585038}
\ket{su093unfs}
\braket{adlkgnaogoaj}
\set{982509unflksndl}
```

OUTPUT file should be:

```
\langle ahdhaodoaddo4092039585038|\sprangle
\splangle|su093unfs\rangle
\langle adlkgnaogoaj\rangle
\{982509unflksndl\}
```

My code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $texfile = "brktt.tex"; my $inifile = "brck.ini";
my $texcnt = ""; my $inicnt = "";

readFileinString($texfile,\$texcnt);
readFileinString($inifile,\$inicnt);

my %iniStore = ();

while($inicnt=~m/^([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)/mgs)
{
    my $find = $1; my $rep = $2;

    $texcnt=~s/$find/$rep/g;
}
```

Could someone help me on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues:

1. `readFileinString` isn't provided, so we don't know exactly what's going on.
2. `[\t]*` matches newlines as well
3. `$1` inside a variable doesn't interpolate in replacement. You need either `/e` or `eval`, but such an approach is fragile and dangerous. I tried to find a better way: just split the replacement on `$1` and glue the parts back with the string `$1` replaced by the real `$1`.
4. `\` need to be doubled to keep their literal meaning.

And some minor ones:

1. `/s` changes what `.` matches, but you use no dot in the regex.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub readFileinString {
    my ($filename, $content) = @_;
    open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "$filename: $!";
    $$content = do { local $/; <$fh> };
}

my ($texfile, $inifile) = @ARGV;

readFileinString($texfile, \ my $texcnt);
readFileinString($inifile, \ my $inicnt);

while ($inicnt =~ /^([^\t]*)\t(.*)/mg) {
    my ($find, $rep) = ($1, $2);
    $find =~ s/\\/\\\\/g;
    my ($pre, $post) = split /\$1/, $rep;
    $texcnt =~ s/$find/$pre$1$post/g;
}

print $texcnt;
```

Comment: `$$content ` & `\ my $texcnt`  I couldn't understand this please.

Comment: @ssr1012: The first one is a de-reference, the second one is a reference. [perlref](http://p3rl.org/perlref). None of them is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You want to evalue the second part of the inifile, so replacing

```
     $texcnt=~s/$find/$rep/g;
```

with

```
     $texcnt=~s/$find/eval "qq($rep)"/eg;
```

might do the job, though using eval is usally a bad (and slow) idea.